# PHP while($content = zip_read()) missing files

Tags: php, zip

Im using script to go through content of zipped files and the script just misses some of them

We have multiple ZIP archives on a server where invoices (Flat files) are stored. Im using following code to search though them:

```
foreach($zip_files as $zip_file){

      echo $zip_file . "[" . $counter . "/" . $count . "]\n";
      $counter++;
      //Opening and reading zip file
      $zip_content = zip_open($archive_path . "\\" . $zip_file); 

      while($file = zip_read($zip_content)){

        $filename = zip_entry_name($file);

        if(strpos($filename,".rcv")){


          $content = zip_entry_read($file,4086);
          if(strpos($content, "<MvxEnvelope>")){

            if(strpos($content, "<Field>TETINR</Field>")){

              $type = "TETINR";
              $TINR_position = strpos($content, "<Field>TETINR");
              $DIVI_position = strpos($content, "<Field>DIVI");
              $TINR = substr($content,($TINR_position + 28), 10);
              $DIVI = substr($content,($DIVI_position + 26), 3);
              fwrite($map, $zip_file . ";" . $filename . ";" . $DIVI . ";" . $TINR . ";" . $type . "\n");

            }
          }
        }
      }   
    }
```

I would like the script to go through all files and not to miss some of them. Many thanks in advance

Comment: FYI: the files I am missing all have .rcv extension

Comment: what you mean with "misses"? Try to echo all the file in the loop with a code like this `echo  zip_entry_name($file);`

Comment: This loop ONLY prints the `.rcv` files because of `if(strpos($filename, ".rcv"))`

Comment: As I stated, i am only looking for .rcv files. The problem is that half of .rcv files that are supoosed to be read just arent processed at all. I will investigate further an let you know if i find out some solution

Comment: Hi fixed the issue. I just wrote it again from scratch and it works.. Don know why though...